# How to address co-variant array conversion?

Tags: c#

I have an image stitching task that could take a lot of time so I run it as a seperate task like this

```
var result = openFileDialog.ShowDialog();
BeginInvoke(new Action<string[]>(StitchTask), openFileDialog.FileNames);

private void StitchTask(string[] fileNames)
{
    // this task could take a lot of time
}
```

Do I need to worry about the co-variant array conversion warning below or am I doing something wrong?

> Co-variant array conversion from string[] to object[] can cause
>   run-time exception on write operation

Comment: What's giving you that warning? I don't see anything using an `object[]`...

Comment: ReSharper is giving the warning.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Got it - the problem is that you're passing a `string[]` as if it were an *array* of arguments for the delegate, when you actually want it as a *single* argument:

```
BeginInvoke(new Action<string[]>(StitchTask),
            new object[] { openFileDialog.FileNames });
```

Whatever's giving you the warning is warning you about the implicit conversion of `string[]` to `object[]`, which is reasonable because something taking an `object[]` parameter *might* try to write:

```
array[0] = new object();
```

In this case that isn't the problem... but the fact that it would try to map each string to a separate delegate parameter *is* a problem.